# iOS TableView reload and scroll top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

the second day I can not solve the problem with the table.

We have a segmentedControl which, when changed, changes the table.
Suppose that there are 3 elements in the segment of the control and, correspondingly, 3 arrays (which is important, they are of different sizes)
I need to scroll table up when segmentedControl is changed.

And it seems like everything is simple: contentOffset = .zero and reloadData ()

But. This does not work, I do not know why the table not scroll up.

The only thing that worked:

```
UIView.animate (withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.tableView.contentOffset = .zero
        }) {(_) in
            self.tableView.reloadData ()
}
```

But now there is another problem when the table goes up, a bug may occur, because the segmentedControl has changed, and the data in the other array may not be, we have not yet done reloadData ()

Maybe I can not understand the obvious things)) Congrats on the upcoming holidays!

Comment: What is your question here and what you want to achieve?

Comment: @RichieRich why the table will not scroll up when I call
self.tableView.setContentOffset (.zero, animated: false)
self.tableView.reloadData ()

Comment: reload your tableview in main thread and check

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`UItableView` method [scrollToRow(at:at:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow) Scrolls through the table view until a row identified by index path is at a particular location on the screen.

**Use**

```
tableView.scroll(to: .top, animated: true)
```

You can use my extension

```
extension UITableView {

    public func reloadData(_ completion: @escaping ()->()) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {
            self.reloadData()
        }, completion:{ _ in
            completion()
        })
    }

    func scroll(to: scrollsTo, animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(300)) {
            let numberOfSections = self.numberOfSections
            let numberOfRows = self.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections-1)
            switch to{
            case .top:
                if numberOfRows > 0 {
                     let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                     self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: animated)
                }
                break
            case .bottom:
                if numberOfRows > 0 {
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows-1, section: (numberOfSections-1))
                    self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }

    enum scrollsTo {
        case top,bottom
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that helped!
The only reason I did not want to use scrollToRow - if there is no data, there will be an error because there is no index (0,0). Tell me, am I right? @AshvinGudaliya

Comment: scrollToRow need an at least one row in table view

Comment: @MikhailSein To solve that you just need to add one check before calling scrollToRow. if let _ = self.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
                    self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
                }

Comment: Why was 300 milliseconds added to dispatch?
Why not just use only .now()?

Comment: @Krekin My table reloads and goes top issues is solve using 300 milliseconds. if you don't need this then you can remove it.

Answer (score 10):

I was getting the following error after trying to scroll to top straight after calling a reloadData

```
[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'
```

This fixed it for me:

```
    tableView.reloadData()
    if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) != 0 {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: This works, the other solutions didn`t, lokks like tableView prefers to receive the position to scroll by indexpath explicitly rather than content offset or just scrolltotop

Answer (score 6):

I found better way to do this. It works like a charm.

```
let topIndex = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: topIndex, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay. So people finding issue with scrolling a tableview to the top with

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
```

And need to do reload data unnecessarily to fix this !

So What is the issue with   `setContentOffset` is kind of bug of iOS ? 
The smallest and simplest answer is **NO** so what's the issue then ?

The answer is that **dynamic row** is using `UITableView.automaticDimension`.  Tableview calculates its content offset with row height and with the number or sections and rows you have in your data source. 
So in case of dynamic height is not performing the scrollToTop correctly, it is because it needs to recalculate every row height and content size.

So to reduce this bundle from tableview we, can provide an estimated row height  like

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 117 // whatever your value
```

Hopefully this will help someone :)

Comment: This is a great answer to this problem...   I tried all forms of scroll-content-offset and tableView-scrollToTop or scroll-to-IndexPath(0,0)...    Nothing seems to work given that my cells are 80.0 in height....

Comment: You rock guy! Thanks!
With a TableView's Header, 
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true) 
went to top, but after the Header

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly to the top of page on reload, by twice reloading

No disturbing animation

```
dataForSource = nil
tableView.reloadData()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) {
    self.dataForSource = realData
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: this seems to be the only thing that works, or vice versa (scrolling to top async after). i use 0.2 sec. nothing else works, not even with animation set to false. it seems like an awful hack though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
```

you can set animated as your requirement

Comment: I tried.
Yes, this works if you do not call reloadData ()

If you call reloadData after the setContentOffset table for some reason does not scroll up.

Comment: then you can call reloadData() function before this. in this way you data will load as well as table view scroll to the top.

Comment: I tried calling it before setContentOffset, still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.1***, tried one line code and worked for me:

```
tableView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Added this code to my tableview to align the content to start from top.

Hope will be helping. :)