# Scrolling to the bottom of collectionView does not work

Tags: ios, swift

I try to scroll to the bottom of the collectionView when the view first loads its items. I run this function inside viewDidLoad:

```
private func fetchMessages() {
    guard let r = replyTo else { return }
    let urlString = "\(Config.URL)/api/messages/replyTo/\(r)/offset/\(offset)"
    guard let authToken = Auth.getToken() else { return }
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(authToken)"]
    Alamofire.request(urlString, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        guard let value = response.result.value else { return }
        let json = JSON(value)
        for messagesJSON in json["messages"].arrayValue {
            let message = Message(json: messagesJSON.dictionaryObject ?? [:])
            self.messages.append(message)
        }
        self.messages.reverse()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
            self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

I get the last indexPath, and then use scrollToItem to scroll to the bottom, but it does not want to scroll to the bottom. It does not scroll at all. Everything works except for the scrolling.

Comment: Use the selectItem method.

Comment: Maybe useful for you try this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018130/6822622

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taimoor's answer is correct (in its essence) but I want to add some background *why*:

`viewDidLoad()` is called when the whole view has been loaded into memory, including all subviews. At this point however, the view has not been **laid out** yet, i.e. the frames of all the subviews have not been set properly yet or in other words: When using Auto Layout, your constraints have not been resolved yet when `viewDidLoad()` is called.

Thus, the collection view's frame is not properly set, yet – its size might still be `.zero`. As a consequence, the collection view cannot scroll any cells into its frame – or at the very least the method `scrollToItem(at:, at:, animated:)` will behave unexpectedly.

The one point where you can be sure that the layout is finished is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. However, please be aware that this method might be called several times during the lifetime of your view controller – whenever something in your layout changes, another layout pass will be triggered. You might not want fetch your data again and again when this happens so you somehow need to keep track of this.

If you want to keep it simple, `viewDidAppear()` will also work because when the view is visible, it obviously has been laid out already but the user might see the scrolling / jumping of the collection view.

`viewWillAppear()` might also work but no guarantees here.

Comment: Do you mean that I should call the function fetchMessages() from somewhere else than viewDidLoad ? Or just the scrolling part? If so, how would you do it after I reload the data for the collectionView in the callback of the http request?

Comment: No, I'd keep `fetchMessages()` in `viewDidLoad()` but only update your data source (i.e. the `messages` property) in its completion closure. Then in that property's `didSet` observer you can update the collection view and do the scrolling (which covers the case that the completion closure from your fetch is executed _after_ your view has been laid out). For the other case you'll also need to update and scroll your collection view when you know that the layout is finished, e.g. inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. This way you only perform the fetch once but always update the c.v. when needed.

Comment: Ok so I update the datasource in the http request conpletion block. And then do a didSet on messages and do the reloadData there. And then when reloadData has done its thing, the viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called, and in there I should just do the scrolling? Should I do a logic check before I do the scrolling? For example if messages.count > 0

Comment: Well, reloadData() and viewDidLayoutSubviews() are independent methods. One does not (necessarily) trigger the other. But when viewDidLayoutSubviews() is called you know for sure that the view has been laid out and all frames – including your collection view’s – have been set correctly. So if at that point in time your data source is already set up (the fetch has returned) it makes sense to perform the reloading and scrolling there. If not, you know that it’s going to return later and in that case you’re safe to do the reloading and scrolling when the fetch returns (didSet() observer).

Comment: viewWillLayoutSubviews worked for me. Simply adding a check to make sure it only triggers the scroll to bottom once the view is loaded the first time ensures that it will not call the scrolling more than once.

Answer (score 2):

**viewDidLoad** is called before elements are visual so certain UI elements cannot be manipulated very well. Things like moving buttons around work but dealing with subviews often does not (like scrolling a CollectionView).

Most of these actions will work best when called in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.So try to do this in **viewWillAppear** or **viewDidAppear**.

Comment: Same problem for me but Taimoor’s answer is working for me thanks ....