# How to let UITableView scroll to the bottom in dynamic height cells?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a UITableView with many cells.
Each cells following it's contents have dynamic height.
But I notice that UITableView sometimes don't scroll the last indexPath when I enter this viewController.
Have any idea to fix it.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

let bottomOffSet = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height)
self.tableView.setContentOffset(bottomOffSet, animated: false)
```

PS: I don't want to use "scrollToRow", because it would trigger tableview's function "*cellForRowAtIndexPath*" many times than "*setContentOffset*".

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: contents.count - 1, section: 0), at: .top, animated: animated)
```

Comment: I don't understand how setting `tableView's` `contentOffset` will scroll to last index path? What exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scroll to the bottom of a UITableView on the iPhone before the view appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770158/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-uitableview-on-the-iphone-before-the-view-appea)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS TableView reload and scroll top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017955/ios-tableview-reload-and-scroll-top)

Comment: @PGDev just like a chat app's chat view, I want to scroll to the newest message.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `scrollToRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, at scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)` ? It the straight forward way to achieve that. And yes `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` is called multiple times due to `tableViewCell's` reusability if the cell is not already visible. It will be called in every case whenever a cell is reused.

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate, because they don't mention about dynamic height cell situation.

Comment: @PGDev I don't like use "scrollToRow" , because if I have 100 messages, it will trigger "cellForRow" 100 times. So, I want to find another way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `tableView's` `contentOffset` to the `tableView's` `contentSize`, i.e.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let bottomOffSet = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height)
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(bottomOffSet, animated: false)
}
```

Set the `contentOffset` in `viewDidAppear`.

Also implement the following `UITableViewDelegate` methods:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 126.0 //Maximum possible cell height
}
```