# UITableview contentoffset sometimes not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, contentoffset

I have the following code in the viewDidAppear:

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height)
        //self.tableView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: false)
        self.tableView.contentOffset = bottomOffset
        }
```

And 85% of time it working well, but some times when I open this viewController tableview rows are on the top, not on the bottom. What's wrong?

Comment: try in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: If that’s in the viewDidAppear then you don’t need to specify the thread to be main also run layoutIfNeeded before you check the content size

Comment: you can try this tableview method : [scrollToRow(at:at:animated:) and check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018130/6822622)

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: I've inserted  self.view.layoutIfNeeded() before bottomOffset, and this solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, this worked for me:

```
self.tableView.contentOffset.y = newPosition
```

as opposed to

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: newPosition))
```

Apple did it again