# Swift 3 - Scroll to top of Tableview on Tabbar Switch

Tags: swift, scroll, tableview

I have a few `UITableViewController's` set up as child-views of `UINavigationController's` that are all part of a single `UITabBarController`. One of these `UITableViewController's` updates a tableViewController that is part of a different `UITableViewController` on a button press, which then switches the currently selected tab via:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

I would like the tableView in the newly selected index, in this case 1,to scroll back to the top automatically on changing between the tabViews. I have tries simply adding :

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
```

To `viewWillAppear()` but this doesn't seem to work. If you scroll to the bottom of the tableView on index 1, then tab over to the tabBarController that updates that index(say index 0), update the index and get switched back to index 1, the tableview for index 1 remains on the same row as when you originally were viewing it. The data is properly loaded, but the actual UI is still on the row you left at. I would like to implement it so that switching between tabs automatically scrolls to the top.

Comment: Try This :-  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018130/6822622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scrollToRow(at:at:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow).

You can add this to the `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` function:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
```

Comment: this will not show the `largeTitle` of the `navigationBar`

Answer (score 3):

You can try using IndexPath and scroll to index `0` of section `0`  :

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: sectionIndex) // set row = 0 and section = 0
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
```