# How does it work scrollToRow(at:at:animated:) in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a chat interface.

User's message is put in a new UITable view cell.

And when update the table view, I use the following code.

```
extension UITableView {

    func scrollToBottom() {
        let rows = self.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)

        if rows > 0 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rows - 1, section: 0)
            self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Actually this works a little better, but there is something strange.

When I turn off the app and turn it on again, or after exiting the screen and entering again, the following issues arise.

The issue is that when I add a new cell, it goes up to the first cell in the table view and back down to the last cell.

As the number of cells increases, the scrolling becomes too fast and too messy.

I just want to keep updating the last cell that is newly registered.

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe you could show us your `viewWillAppear` and/or `viewDidAppear` functions?

Comment: Did you tried to set `animated:` to `false`, I mean using this:
`self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)`

Comment: @T.BenjaminLarsen I don't use viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear...The issue is that when I add a new cell, it goes up to the first cell in the table view and back down to the last cell.

Comment: @SeyedSamadGholamzadeh I didn't try that. I'll try now.

Comment: You can try out this post code:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018130/6822622

Comment: OK, could you show us where you create the new cells then?

Comment: @T.BenjaminLarsen `func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    
    guard let text = textField.text else { return false }
    
    chatData.append(text)
    
    textField.text = ""
    chatTableView.reloadData()
    chatTableView.scrollToBottom()
    
    return true
}`

Comment: @SeyedSamadGholamzadeh If the animated is false, there is no such issue. But can not animation use forever?

Comment: You're calling `reloadData()` but you probably want `reloadSections(_)` ...

Comment: @allanWay You can use `animated: true` for some special scrolls that you really want to show a beautiful scroll animation to your user, but in this case it's better to set the value of `animated:` to `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        let newText = (textView.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)
        let numberOfChars = newText.characters.count // for Swift use count(newText)
        let typedStr : String = textView.text
        var compArr = typedStr.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        _ = newText.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        self.sendBtn.setTitle("Send", forState: .Normal)

        if numberOfChars > 0 {

            self.sendBtn.enabled = true
        }
        else {

            self.TextViewHeight.constant = TEXTVIEW_OFFSET
            self.sendBtn.enabled = false
        }
        let  char = text.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")

        if text == "\n"
        {
            print("Return_Pressed")
            if  compArr.count == 1 || compArr.count == 2 || compArr.count == 3
            {
                self.TextViewHeight.constant =  self.TextViewHeight.constant + 25
                self.tableViewScrollToBottom(false)
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }



func tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                let numberOfSections = self.ChatTableView.numberOfSections
                let numberOfRows = self.ChatTableView.numberOfRowsInSection(numberOfSections-1)

                if numberOfRows > 0 {

                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: (numberOfSections-1))
                    self.ChatTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: animated)
                }

            }
    }
```

Comment: I want use animated=true. but this case animated=false... I already know that. but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your `scrollToBottom` function in `viewWillAppear` method. Maybe it just needs to update the number of rows when you return to your TableViewController.