# How to focus last cell in the UITableview in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a chat interface.

User's message is put in a new UITable view cell.

And when update the table view, I use the following code.

```
extension UITableView {

    func scrollToBottom() {
        let rows = self.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)

        if rows > 0 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rows - 1, section: 0)
            self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Actually this works a little better, but there is something strange.

When I turn off the app and turn it on again, or after exiting the screen and entering again, the following issues arise.

The issue is that when I add a new cell, it goes up to the first cell in the table view and back down to the last cell.

See the issue(https://vimeo.com/266821436)

As the number of cells increases, the scrolling becomes too fast and too messy.

I just want to keep updating the last cell that is newly registered.

What should I do?

Comment: When are you changing the tableView's inset in case keyboard appears?

Comment: Can you put some println for the index path in scrollToBottom?
This will show if it is called with index less than the rows count and how many times the method is called.
Also if you are triggering it with event and adding the listener on viewWillAppear, don't forget to remove it when you leave the screen.

Comment: @DanielAlexandrov print index path is It comes out normally. and I'm not use event listner on viewWillapear or viewdidappear, viewdidload...

Comment: And how do you update your datasource?

Comment: @DanielAlexandrov Update in a very standard way.

I write in a text field and press enter to add the article to a specific array and reload the table view. After reloading, execute the scrollToBottom method.

Comment: You probably have another call that forces the table view to scroll up. Maybe you empty your dataSource, refresh, fill your dataSource, refresh or something strange like this. Can you provide more code (via a gist if you have too much code)

Comment: You can try out this post:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018130/6822622

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use DispatchQueue to Scroll because of the method you are fire is executed with tableView load data so we need to give time to scroll.

```
extension UITableView {

    func scrollToBottom() {
        let rows = self.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)

        if rows > 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rows - 1, section: 0)
                self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
func scrollToBottom(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.array.count-1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it fails, but it's still the best of all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath.last ...)

Comment: Table view does not scroll if index path not visible.