# How to scroll to Tableview Top in Pagination?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I have pagination in my tableview and I scroll to bottom close to 5-6 pagination iterations down.

How do I scroll to top of the UITableview.

Solutions that I have tried with SO solutions
Sol 1:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        }
```

Sol 2:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
        }
```

Sol 3:

```
tableView.scroll(to: .top, animated: true)
```

Sol 4:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018130

whenever I am trying, I have checked the Scrollview contentsize of the tableview

The overall scroll is
tableview.scrollview contentSize = [(414.0, 30662.666544596355)]
when I tap on the button to scroll to top = [(0.0, 28960.0)], gradually it is decreasing, Ideally it should to top and make [(0.0, 0.0)] right ?

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: *"I have pagination in my tableview"* -- what is that doing? Is it running code while you're trying to "scroll to top"?

Comment: @DonMag : This is just information that, there is some api getting called every time data is completed from the previous request.

Comment: I'd suggest putting some `print()` statements in your "api call" to make sure it's not being triggered and trying to update the table at the same time.

Comment: ok Sure. @DonMag